# Laravel cant submit ajax forms appended by javascript

Tags: ajax, forms, laravel, submit

I have implemented infinite scroll that appends html in the exact same manner as the static item with forms (inclusive csrf), but the dynamic forms that has been appended seems to be submitting without ajax and failing when pressing the submit button.

I get this error on the appended forms in console log:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json:
```

The ajax submit.

```
$('.cart_add').on('submit',function (event) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content'));
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("item has been added to cart");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
});
```

Edit I noticed that the jquery doesn't select the dynamically appended forms

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your content type. The content type is the type of data sent to the server. In this case, you are sending data to the server which is interpreted as a Document (html) but is sent as json. This is because the browser is trying to infer what type of data your are sending becuase you did not explicitly state it.

Use the contentType to set it.

```
contentType: "text/html"
```

So your call should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    contentType: "text/html",
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content'));
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("item has been added to cart");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Edited description

Comment: Where are you getting the error? On the browser side or server side?

Comment: Solved it by doing $(document).on('submit', 'card_add' function()